# sftp and sshfs don't work on Ubuntu VM 18.04, while ssh and scp work fine

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, sftp, sshfs

I have installed an Ubuntu 18.04 on an windows 7 machine.
I try to map a folder from local host VM to a target hardware module that runs linux yocto.
I gave the following but with no success :

```
sshfs -o nonempty root@xx.xx.xx.x:/target/path /home/user/local/path
```

When I gave the above command with debug options :

```
sshfs -odebug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug root@xx.xx.xx.x:/target/path /home/user/local/path
```

after giving password I got :

```
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = el_GR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = el_GR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = el_GR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = el_GR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = el_GR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = el_GR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = el_GR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = el_GR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = el_GR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2392, received 2564 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 142525.2, received 152773.6
debug1: Exit status 127
remote host has disconnected
```

After searching several sites the most common advice is to modifiy the config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
The `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` exists in my system so I tried both with it and the `internal-sftp` but the I get the same error.

Furthermore I tried to connect via nautilus and sftp and got `"Unable to access location"`.
I also tried filezilla via sftp  and then I received `unexpected end-of-file` error.
On the other hand ssh and scp work fine.
The sshd_config file I use is the following:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Is it a problem on host or on target and how can I get more info to identify if possible?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  I added the shhd_config file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I tried with everything from Match group sftp to the end removed but the problem persists.